# How to measure the consolidated power of two electric motors, operating on separate axles of a 4x4 vehicle?

Tags: power, motor, measurement

There may be two scenarios:
1- motors are identical
2- motors are not identical

I wish to know about the consolidated power for:
1- maximum power
2- continuous power.

Comment: power adds linearly. So if you want to know the total power of the two motors, which is what I think you mean by 'consolidated', then measure the power of each alone and add. Being on the same vehicle will constrain them to run at the same wheel periphery speed, so make sure you measure each at an appropriate speed.

Comment: Put the motors on a dyno and test or get a dyno that does 4*4. The latter will give you power at the wheels.

Comment: Thank you! I have seen some exmaples that adding up the front and rear axle powers do not give the max power. E.g. Taycan, Tesla ("With the shaft horsepower coming out of the motors the situation is not always as simple as front + rear." noted at https://www.tesla.com/blog/tesla-all-wheel-drive-dual-motor-power-and-torque-specifications. Testing on 4x4 dyno is the best option but I am searching if a simpler option may be achieved. For example I have though adding up the torque values at the same rpm and calculation power would be possible but the examples also do not show so.

Comment: After searcing for similar cases, I believe if the engines at the front and rear axles are different, you cannot simply add up. What if the engines are the same?